# Facebook and image post

Tags: php, facebook

I want to post into community wall post with attached image. If I use simple api call to `/page/feed` with `picture` arguments it inserts a small image. But I want to attach big image, for example, from gallery. When I upload photo to gallery it automatically posts to wall. But when I post >= 3 photos all that posts are merged into single one with all inserted images.

The question is how to get different post for each uploaded image? Or maybe I can attach to `/page/feed` api not `picture` only, but image which would be uploaded into album?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you say "attach big image", I assume you are POSTing to /PAGE_ID/photos, right?
If you upload 3 or more images, yes, they will be collapsed when they are displayed in the page's feed.  This is a "feature" of feed that organizes and collapses images that were uploaded together.

Imagine if you uploaded 20 photos to the page and they weren't collapsed; the feed would be dominated by the photos and it would be hard to see any other content (like content that was published slightly before the uploaded photos).

If you can provide a screenshot of what you are seeing, I can confirm this.

And yes `/PAGE_ID/feed` with `picture` is a thumbnail for a post. Example: a thumbnail to accompany a post containing a paragraph of text (or a link).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/